# How to choose and join any number of strings in matlab?

Tags: matlab

The function `output_cellstrings = choose_and_combine(varargin)` can accepts arbitrary number of cell string inputs. The number of inputs and the length of each cell string array are arbitrary.

Each time We choose one element from each cell array and join them to make a string as the element of the output cell strings. The output consists of all the possible combinations.

If we have `k` inputs and their length is `n1`, `n2`, ..., `nk`, the length of the output cell strings would be `n1*n2*...*nk`.

The results should be like,

```
>> choose_and_combine({'a1','a2'},{'b1'})
'a1b1' 'a2b1'

>> choose_and_combine({'a1','a2'},{'b1'},{'c1','c2'})
'a1b1c1' 'a1b1c2' 'a2b1c1' 'a2b1c2'

>> choose_and_combine({'a1','a2'},{'b1','b2','b3'},{'c1','c2'})
'a1b1c1'    'a1b1c2'    'a1b2c1'    'a1b2c2'    'a1b3c1'    'a1b3c2'    'a2b1c1'    'a2b1c2'    'a2b2c1'    'a2b2c2'    'a2b3c1'    'a2b3c2'
```

Comment: We need some more information. What did *you* try to do?

Comment: so what happens when you have {'a1','a2','a3'} , {'b1','b2'} and {'c1','c2'}?

Comment: @GameOfThrows all the possible combinations.

Comment: @Jørgen I thought the simple examples in the first post have been clear enough. It looks I'm over-optimistic. Somebody got it and some not.

Comment: how could a question be put on hold as unclear even after there have been good answers??????

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that you are trying to create cartesian product of those cell arrays of strings, i.e. combine them in all possible ways taking one string from each input.

The following function would do that. Resulting order of strings is slightly different than in your example, but I presume that's not an issue:

```
function out = choose_and_combine(varargin)
    indices = cellfun(@(x) 1:length(x), varargin, 'uni', false);
    [cartProdIdx{1:length(varargin)}] = ndgrid(indices{:});
    combinations = cellfun(@(strs,idx) reshape(strs(idx(:)),[],1), varargin, cartProdIdx, 'uni', false);
    out = strcat(combinations{:})';
end

>> choose_and_combine({'a1','a2'},{'b1'},{'c1','c2'})
ans = 
    'a1b1c1'    'a2b1c1'    'a1b1c2'    'a2b1c2'

>> choose_and_combine({'a1','a2'},{'b1'})
ans = 
    'a1b1'    'a2b1'
```

Comment: why it's called `cartesian product `?

Comment: Wikipedia: [Cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product)

Comment: Yes, looks the same idea. Thanks for info.

Comment: And also thanks for the dynamic varargout. I didn't know that way.

Answer (score 1):

Just for the record, another possible solution (using [ind2sub](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ind2sub.html)):

```
function out = choose_and_combine(varargin)

[idx{1:nargin}] = ind2sub(cellfun(@numel, varargin), 1:prod(cellfun(@numel, varargin)));
out = cellfun(@(x) strjoin(arrayfun(@(i) varargin{i}{x(i)}, 1:numel(varargin), 'Un', 0), ''), num2cell(cell2mat(idx')', 2), 'Un', 0);
```